# Magento 2: toolbar url problems in custom module with custom router

Tags: magento2, collection, toolbar, router

I have the custom module with product collection and custom router.

for example i want to have link https://domain.com/gaires/something

Router code:

```
namespace UseApp\Gaires\Controller;
class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    protected $actionFactory;
    protected $_response;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }

    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $exlpoded = array_filter(explode('/', trim($request->getPathInfo()) ) );
        if($exlpoded && $exlpoded[1]=='gaires' && count($exlpoded)>=2){
            $request->setModuleName('gaires')
                ->setControllerName('index')
                ->setActionName('gaire')
                ->setParam('q', urldecode($exlpoded[2]));
        }
    }
}
```

Router working fine.

In the page (controller) gaires/index/gaire I have product collection with toolbar (sorter, limeter, pagger )

The problem is that the bad url address in the pager, sorter and limiter links.

For example: http://domain.com/gaires/index/gaire/q/something/?p=2

address must be: http://domain.com/gaires/something?p=2

If I change the adres in browser url field manually (http://domain.com/gaires/something?p=2) Router and collection working fine, but toolbar links also no

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

after

```
$request->setModuleName('gaires')
        ->setControllerName('index')
        ->setActionName('gaire')
        ->setParam('q', urldecode($exlpoded[2]));
```

You add

```
$request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\Url::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, YOUR_NEW_PATH_HERE);
```

That "YOUR_NEW_PATH_HERE" is what the pagination is looking at.